# How to identify Marathon App deployment failure due to resource exhaustion via API?

Tags: mesosphere, marathon

I am creating a Marathon apps using POST on the 'v2/apps' REST interface. If I attempt to create an app which does not have available resources on the underlying mesos cluster (in this case host_port), the app creation still returns an S_OK while the app is stuck in deploying forever (status never switches to running).

Is there a way to fail the application creation API in case resources are unavailable - or atleast - to query the state and identify that the application is stuck deploying due to resource exhaustion to fail fast?

Answer (score 2):

Marathon is "the second layer" scheduler running on top of Mesos. It is exposed only to the resources allocated to it by Mesos. Marathon has no global cluster view, and hence it has no idea whether requested resources are available somewhere in the cluster or will be available in the future.

When you submit an app to Marathon, it validates the request, accepts it, and waits for a suitable offer from Mesos. In your case, you know a suitable offer will not come in the near future (I suppose because there is another task using that particular port on that particular agent), but Marathon is not aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the statuses that marathon-ui uses:
https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/marathon-ui.html#application-status-reference

The one you are looking for is likely the `waiting` state which you can identify by querying `v2/queue` and checking if `queueEntry.delay.overdue === true` for an extended period.

I've just built some `prometheus` alarms to be alarmed for similar issues like the one you describe, see the MarathonAppCantGetSuitableOffers alarm here:
https://github.com/bergerx/prom_marathon_app_exporter#alerts-on-prometheus